# tkinter change color of bg and fg while programme is running

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to programme my own notepad. As a function, I want to be able to toggle between white mode and dark mode.

This is my code so far. I know that the problem is that the variables color_fg and color_bg are not transferred to the top, but I just can't find a solution for it.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

color_fg = "#dbdbdb"
color_bg = "#282b33"

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Improved Notepad)")
root.geometry("800x600")

text_widget = tk.Text(root, bg=color_bg, fg=color_fg)
text_widget.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

menu_bar = tk.Menu(root, bg=color_bg, fg=color_fg)

dark_mode = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)

# File menu
file_menu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0, bg=color_bg, fg=color_fg)


def open_text():
    filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        text = f.read()
    text_widget.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    text_widget.insert(1.0, text)


def save_text():
    filepath = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".txt")
    text = text_widget.get(1.0, tk.END)
    with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
        f.write(text)


file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=open_text)
file_menu.add_command(label="Save", command=save_text)
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)


# Settings menu
def toggle_dark_mode():
    if dark_mode.get():
        color_fg = "#dbdbdb"
        color_bg = "#282b33"
        dark_mode.set(False)
    else:
        color_fg = "#000000"
        color_bg = "#FFFFFF"
        dark_mode.set(True)


settings_menu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0, bg=color_bg, fg=color_fg)
dark_mode_toggle = tk.Checkbutton(settings_menu, text="Dark Mode", variable=dark_mode, onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
settings_menu.add_checkbutton(label="Dark Mode", command=toggle_dark_mode)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=settings_menu)


root.config(menu=menu_bar)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly change the color in the widget. Also, you aren't associating the variable with the checkbutton menu item. You're associating it with a separate `Checkbutton` widget that you don't seem to use anywhere.

The following is a working version of your code, with the File menu and some other unnecessary code removed to keep the example short. The key points are:

1. the call to `settings_menu.add_checkbutton` adds the `variable` option to tie it to the variable
2. `toggle_dark_mode` explicitly changes the `background` and `foreground` options of the text widget.

```
import tkinter as tk

color_fg = "#dbdbdb"
color_bg = "#282b33"

def toggle_dark_mode():
    if dark_mode.get():
        text_widget.configure(foreground=color_fg, background=color_bg)
    else:
        text_widget.configure(foreground=color_bg, background=color_fg)

root = tk.Tk()
dark_mode = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)

text_widget = tk.Text(root, bg=color_bg, fg=color_fg)
text_widget.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

menu_bar = tk.Menu(root, bg=color_bg, fg=color_fg)
settings_menu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0, bg=color_bg, fg=color_fg)
settings_menu.add_checkbutton(label="Dark Mode", command=toggle_dark_mode, variable=dark_mode)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=settings_menu)

# sync the color mode with the menu
toggle_dark_mode()

root.config(menu=menu_bar)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 I want to be able to toggle between white mode and dark mode.
```

- I added an extra function for white mode.
- I added `settings_menu.add_checkbutton` to the Setting menu.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Improved Notepad)")
root.geometry("800x600")

text_widget = tk.Text(root, bg=color_bg, fg=color_fg)
text_widget.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

menu_bar = tk.Menu(root, bg=color_bg, fg=color_fg)

dark_mode = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)

# File menu
file_menu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0, bg=color_bg, fg=color_fg)

def open_text():
    filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        text = f.read()
    text_widget.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    text_widget.insert(1.0, text)

def save_text():
    filepath = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".txt")
    text = text_widget.get(1.0, tk.END)
    with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
        f.write(text)

file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=open_text)
file_menu.add_command(label="Save", command=save_text)
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)

dark_color_fg = "#dbdbdb"
dark_color_bg = "#282b33"

white_color_fg = "#000000"
white_color_bg = "#FFFFFF"

# Settings menu
def toggle_dark_mode():
    text_widget.configure(fg=dark_color_fg, bg=dark_color_bg)

def toggle_white_mode():    
    text_widget.configure(fg=white_color_fg, bg=white_color_bg)
     

settings_menu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0, bg=color_bg, fg=color_fg)
dark_mode_toggle = tk.Checkbutton(settings_menu, text="Dark Mode", variable=dark_mode, onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
settings_menu.add_checkbutton(label="Dark Mode", command=toggle_dark_mode)

white_mode_toggle = tk.Checkbutton(settings_menu, text="White Mode", variable=dark_mode, onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
settings_menu.add_checkbutton(label="White Mode", command=toggle_white_mode)

menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=settings_menu)

root.config(menu=menu_bar)
root.mainloop()
```

Screenhot:

[image]